# Ethereum lottery smart contract reverts due to insufficient funds. Where does my code consumes that much gas?

Tags: solidity, transfer

I am experimenting with solidity and I faced an issue for what I could not find a solution.
The program should let addresses buy ticket at a preset price, and the owner can start the "roll the dice" function which randomly selects the winner and transfer the funds to that address.

I beleive that this program would be easier with mapping instead of array, but getting experience with array was the main purpose of this program.

The error happens when the user calls buyTicket function. Based on the response I beleive the contract comsumes too much gas. Can someone tell me why it doesnt work? I appreciate any other helping comment regarding the rest of the code:)

Thanks in advance!

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Lottery {

constructor () {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

address[] public Players;
address private owner;

uint public ticketPrice;
uint public price;
uint public nonce;
uint public variations;
address payable winner;
bool hasTicketAnswer;

event Winner(address _winner);
event PriceSet(uint _setPrice);
event TicketBought();

function setTicketPrice(uint _ticketPrice) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Only Owner...");
    ticketPrice = _ticketPrice;

    emit PriceSet(_ticketPrice);
}

function hasTicket(address _sender) private returns(bool) {
    hasTicketAnswer = false;
    for (uint i = 0; i < Players.length; i++) {
        if (Players[i] == _sender) hasTicketAnswer = true;
    }
    return hasTicketAnswer;
}

function buyTicket() external payable {
    require(ticketPrice > 0, "Price did not set, be patient...");
    require(hasTicket(msg.sender) == false, "You cannot have two tickets...");
    require(msg.sender.balance <= ticketPrice, "Insufficient funds...");
    payable(address(this)).transfer(ticketPrice);
    Players.push(address(msg.sender));
    price += msg.value;

    emit TicketBought();
}

function checkBalance() public view returns(uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
}

function rollTheDice() public payable {
    variations = Players.length;
    winner = payable(Players[uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, nonce, block.timestamp))) %  variations]);
    winner.transfer(price);

    emit Winner(winner);
}

receive () external payable  {

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides probably finding the problem, I've read some things that I'd like to comment on.

**Your problem**

The reason why you're getting the "Insufficient funds" error is because the condition is returning false. You're asking the msg.sender balance to be less than or equal (<=) to ticketPrice, when it should be more than or equal (>=).

Let's say Alice has a balance of 0.05 ETH and interacts with the contract whose ticket price is 0.001 ETH...

```
require(0.05 ETH <= 0.001 ETH) // Reverting...
```

**Observations**

1. I'm curious if you're intentionally coding the buyTicket function in that way. What it actually does is checking if the msg.sender has enough ETH to buy a ticket in its wallet, which doesn't mean that the user is effectively sending ETH in the transaction (the amount of wei sent in the transaction can be checked with msg.value, you can read more about it [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43362/what-is-msg-value)).
2. My last observation is the `payable(address(this)).transfer(ticketPrice)` line of code, because it's not necessary to do so, once a payable function receives ETH, it is saved into the contract... In that line you're just making the Bob's contract to send ETH to the Bob's contract, which just wastes gas without reason

I hope I've helped with you and if I wasn't completely clear in any thing I've said don't doubt in asking me